# Flutter: Updating UI from outside of a StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am new to flutter, and working on a shopping cart project. i don't know how exatly i am suppose to ask this question but, here is what i wanted.
I am trying to update my UI when the cart item and prices changes, which means to display sum amount of products from ListView (Stateful widget) to main OrderPage Stateful widget.  I know about `setState()` method, but i think i should use some callback methods here, dont know exactly.

> I have explained in short in Image - see below img

What i have done: when user modify cart products, I have saved the value (price/product/count) in to constant value , i calculate the value and save in constant value, and later use that const var in Main widget (Main Ui), which does update when i close and reopen the page, but could not able to update when button pressed (product +/-buttons)

What i want to do is,

> Update my total value when +/- buttons are pressed.
>
> Here is my full code:

```
  class cartConstant{
  static int packageCount;
  static List<int> list;
}
class OrderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderPageState createState() => _OrderPageState();
}

class _OrderPageState extends State<OrderPage> {
  int data = 3;
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black54, //change your color here
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 1,
          title: Text("Your order Summery",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child:
          FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot){
//            var datas = snapshot.data;
              return
                ListView.builder(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
//                Cart cart = datas[index];
                    return CartListView();
                  },
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _buildTotalContainer(),
      );
    }
    Widget _buildTotalContainer() {
      return Container(
        height: 220.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10.0,
          right: 10.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Subtotal",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    cartConstant.packageCount.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Discount",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  "0.0",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 2.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Cart Total",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  cartConstant.packageCount.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
//              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SignInPage()));
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Proceed To Checkout",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

}


class CartListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartListViewState createState() => _CartListViewState();

}

class _CartListViewState extends State<CartListView> {
  int _counter = 1;
  int getPrice(int i,int priceC){
    cartConstant.packageCount = i*priceC;
    return cartConstant.packageCount;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3), width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _counter++;
                            if (_counter > 20) {
                              _counter = 20;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3))),
                    Text(
                      "$_counter",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap:(){
                          setState(() {
                            _counter--;
                            if (_counter < 2) {
                              _counter = 1;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20.0,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70.0,
              width: 70.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/food.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0))
                  ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20.0,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Employee Package",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Container(
                  height: 25.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Price",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5.0,
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              getPrice(_counter, 2000).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {

              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can also check from my cart screen shot below:

[image: img]

Comment: The magic word is `setState()`

Comment: @Sukhi i know that but i don't know how to use it for my case. can you exactly tell me how to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `callback refresh()` and pass `callback` to `CartListView` 
code snippet

```
class _OrderPageState extends State<OrderPage> {
  int data = 3;

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }
...
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//                Cart cart = datas[index];
                return CartListView(refresh);
              },

...  
class CartListView extends StatefulWidget {
  VoidCallback callback;

  CartListView(this.callback);

...
InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _counter++;
                            if (_counter > 20) {
                              _counter = 20;
                            }
                          });

                          widget.callback();
                        },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cartConstant {
  static int packageCount;
  static List<int> list;
}

class OrderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderPageState createState() => _OrderPageState();
}

class _OrderPageState extends State<OrderPage> {
  int data = 3;

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black54, //change your color here
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 1,
        title: Text(
          "Your order Summery",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
//            var datas = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: data,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//                Cart cart = datas[index];
                return CartListView(refresh);
              },
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildTotalContainer(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTotalContainer() {
    return Container(
      height: 220.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 10.0,
        right: 10.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Subtotal",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  cartConstant.packageCount.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Discount",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                "0.0",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 2.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Cart Total",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                "8000",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
//              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SignInPage()));
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 50.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Proceed To Checkout",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartListView extends StatefulWidget {
  VoidCallback callback;

  CartListView(this.callback);
  @override
  _CartListViewState createState() => _CartListViewState();
}

class _CartListViewState extends State<CartListView> {
  int _counter = 1;
  int getPrice(int i, int priceC) {
    cartConstant.packageCount = i * priceC;
    return cartConstant.packageCount;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3), width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _counter++;
                            if (_counter > 20) {
                              _counter = 20;
                            }
                          });

                          widget.callback();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3))),
                    Text(
                      "$_counter",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _counter--;
                            if (_counter < 2) {
                              _counter = 1;
                            }
                          });

                          widget.callback();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20.0,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70.0,
              width: 70.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/food.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0))
                  ]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20.0,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Employee Package",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Container(
                  height: 25.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Price",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFFD3D3D3),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5.0,
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              getPrice(_counter, 2000).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: OrderPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the button is tapped, you just need to update the Subtotal amount and cart total.

Step 1 : Replace the harcoded value by a variable. So, something like :

```
Row(
       children: <Widget>[
           Text(
               "Subtotal",
               style: ...
          ),
          Text(
              "$subTotal",
              style: ....
         ),
       ],
 ),
```

Step 2 : Now, add a code to calcualte `subTotal` and `cartTotal`. You already have code which increments and decrements the variable `_counter`. You just need to tweak that part like :

```
setState( (){
    _counter++;
    // So, the quantity is increased. Just get the price of current item and add in the sub total.
    subTotal += priceC;
    cartTotal = subTotal - discount;
} );
```

Comment: Hy brother, thanks for help,but Have you gone through my problem? i have saved value in constant so i did not have any hardcoded value, the value for subtotal is saved value in cartConstant--> cartConstant.packageCount.toString(), i want to get update this value when i press +/- in listview, rest i will do, don't know how to do it in flutter. ;(

Comment: Yes, I did. And I see total cart value is hardcoded to "8000". The setState updaetes the value instantly on the screen. You are calculating the values but with a fixed formula  of quantity x price which is just good to show the price in front of the particular item.

Comment: sry brother, i am talking about subtotal value

                  Text(
                    "Subtotal",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    cartConstant.packageCount.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF6C6D6D),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),

Comment: I understand that.  The code snippet I gave has both the values - sub total and cart total. You just need ensure variable 'priceC' has the correct in there.